# How do I return a CSV from a Pylons app?

Tags: python, csv, pylons

I'm trying to return a CSV from an action in my webapp, and give the user a prompt to download the file or open it from a spreadsheet app. I can get the CSV to spit out onto the screen, but how do I change the type of the file so that the browser recognizes that this isn't supposed to be displayed as HTML? Can I use the csv module for this?

```
import csv

def results_csv(self):

    data = ['895', '898', '897']

    return data
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To tell the browser the type of content you're giving it, you need to set the `Content-type` header to 'text/csv'. In your Pylons function, the following should do the job:

`response.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/csv'`

Answer (score 9):

PAG is correct, but furthermore if you want to suggest a name for the downloaded file you can also set `response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=suggest.csv'`

Comment: This helps, but the file has the name "suggest.csv.html" Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: with both response headers (content type and content disposition) set properly?  What browser is exhibiting this peculiar .html - appending behavior?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the csv module for this:

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO
```

...

```
def results_csv(self):
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    s = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(s)
    writer.writerow(['header', 'header', 'header'])
    writer.writerow([123, 456, 789])
    return s.getvalue()
```